# how to put the value inside the input tag in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am tying to post the Form data form Javascript here I am getting two values and I assigned to two variables now I need to post these two values from javascript file only but I can't assign these values into input tag

```
    <div id="richTextArea" style="border: 2px solid rgb(40, 110, 89);width: 400px;height: 100%">
    <iframe id="comments" name="comments" frameborder="0" 
    align="left" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe><br>
    <input type="hidden" id=Task_ID value=<%= status_info[i].Task_ID%> name="Task_ID">
    <button type="Submit" id=cmtSend title="Submit above Comment.." align="left" style="border: 2px solid rgb(40, 110, 89); width: 400px">Send</button>
    </div>

    cmtSend.addEventListener("click", function () {
    var cmnt_Val = document.getElementById('comments').contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML
    var task_ID = document.getElementById('Task_ID').value
    //cmnt_Val having "welcome" and task_ID having 100001
    if(cmnt_Val == ""){
        alert("please enter the comment ...")
    }
    else {
        alert(cmnt_Val)
        let form = document.createElement('form');
        form.action = '/StatusData';
        form.method = 'Post';
        form.innerHTML += '<input name="Comments" value=cmnt_Val>';
        form.innerHTML += '<input name="Task_ID" value=task_ID>';
        document.body.append(form);
        form.submit();
    }
    }, false)
```

Here I click the submit button I am getting below result in the console

```
{ Comments: 'cmnt_Val', Task_ID: 'task_ID' }
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, and assuming variables `cmnt_Val` and `task_ID` have some value you can't use them inside the value like you did, you should do:

```
 form.innerHTML += ('<input name="Comments" value="'+cmnt_Val+'">');
 form.innerHTML += ('<input name="Task_ID" value="'+task_ID+'">');
```

Please let me know if that helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but I think the problem is that you not assigned variable to inputs:

```
form.innerHTML += '<input name="Comments" value="'+cmnt_Val+'">';
form.innerHTML += '<input name="Task_ID" value="'+task_ID+'">';
```

Comment: It was a copy from my answer  without the parenthesis? xD

Comment: Ta Peter i am getting the value but if i am sendig html data that will not come completey Ex:1 welcome to genpact this will working but Ex 2: <font color=> this will coming instead of <font color="#ff0000" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);">pavan kumar</font>

Comment: @JPeter No this is not copy you posted your answer while I was writing my answer. See the timing

Comment: @pawankumarmothkuri I'm not sure what your trying to do, but probably you need to think about your form template, is not a common thing want to put html inside an input field, for that kind of adding/editing it would just be a lot better using an richtext editor... but answering your question you should encode the html like so: > becomes &gt; --- < becomes &lt; --- " becomes &quot; ---  ' becomes \'